# Display the list view on button command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I having the following xaml and code of the view model,currently I bind the screen list view to the view model .
the user control have text box and button and when the user click on the button (Go) I want to get the data from the view ,how should I do that?

currently I **always** get the data when I run the window but

> I want the list to be empty when I open the page and when I click on
>   the GO button the list will be filled

```
<Grid  Width="877" Height="632" 
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConfigServiceModelViewDataSource}}" >
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ViewModel:ConfigServiceModelView x:Key="ConfigServiceModelViewDataSource" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CollectionTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListView Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="230" 
 Margin="5,20,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding GetCollection}" }" >
<Button Content="Go" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="21.96" />
```

in the ***ModelView*** Im getting the data from the model like

```
internal class ConfigModelView {
   private  ConfigServiceModel _configServiceModel = new ConfigServiceModel();

   public List<string> GetServiceCollection {
      get { 
         return _configServiceModel.CollectList; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `I want to get the data from the view ,how should I do that` - using DataBinding. BTW, Your question is completely unclear can you clarify please?

Comment: In that case populate your list only when the button been clicked.

Comment: @HighCore-  updated ,hope its clear now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> ViewModel

```
public class ConfigModelView
{
    public ConfigModelView()
    {
        GetServiceCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    bool isDataLoaded = false;

    MyCommand goCommand;
    public ICommand GoCommand
    {
        get { return goCommand ?? (goCommand = new MyCommand(() => OnGoCommand(), () => !isDataLoaded)); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> GetServiceCollection { get; set; }

    void OnGoCommand()
    {
        GetServiceCollection.Clear();

        foreach (var item in _configServiceModel.CollectList)
        {
            GetServiceCollection.Add(item);
        }

        isDataLoaded = true;
        goCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

    }
}
```

> Custom Command .You can use RelayCommand

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private Func<bool> _canExecute;
    public MyCommand(Action action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    { 
        if(CanExecuteChanged!=null)
            CanExecuteChanged(this,new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

> xaml

```
<Button Content="Go" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="21.96" Command="{Binding GoCommand}"/>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for help ,voted up :) ,I have test your code ,there is something that is missing ,what should I implement in the =>command?since currently when I try use your code I got error in the command new MyCommand(()=>Command(),true))

Comment: Btw,there is a way after I have press on the GO button and get the data ,to disable it?

Comment: Yes there was one paranthesis missing I copied and pasted it to VS i got the same error. I updated the answer

Comment: Yes it is easily possible by commands to disable once data is fetched.I updated entire answer according to your requirement. Enableing Disableing magic will be set by setting isDataLoaded true or false  and then calling goCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();. You need to understand how command works and you will see its damn easy.

Comment: Thanks Expert you are assume ,Can you please explain how the button know to be disabled since im not able to understand it,i don't see anywhere where you are referring to the button just the Boolean,